# C++: Group integers by common radix to save memory

Tags: c++, performance, vector, integer, ram

Consider a (sorted) vector of unsigned int values.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> data = {1234,1254,1264,1265,1267,1268,1271,1819,1832,1856,
                                  1867,1892,3210,3214,3256,3289};
```

Assuming each unsigned int is 4 bytes, this vector of 16 elements would take at least 64 bytes of RAM.

I am thinking it would be possible to reduce the memory usage by grouping those values by common radix. Consider for example a data representation of the kind

```
data =
{
   {12..
      ..34, ..54, ..64, ..65, ..67, ..68, ..71
   },
   {18..
      ..19, ..32, ..56, ..67, ..92
   }
   {32..
      ..10, ..14, ..56, ..89
   }
};
```

In the above example, I grouped the values by blocks of a 100. It would be more logical to group data by a group of 2^8=256 or of 2^16=65536.

Is there a data type (in std:: or boost:: or other) that can do this kind of trick for me or do I have to code my own type of container for that? Does it sound like a potentially good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a workable idea for particular inputs in very constrained scenarios. Alas the std:: does not provide that structure. Your particular suggestion could reasonably be implemented in a tree like fashion.

Beware of general radix aware ordering as they generally use big lists, hence using more memory than a regular vector would.